# Extending a map of a surface's boundary

Tags: differential-topology, surfaces, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm reading the section in McDuff and Salamon's *Introduction to Symplectic Topology* on Chern numbers on surfaces. I've run into an elementary-looking detail in a proof that I don't see a clear reason why is true.

If $\Sigma$ is a compact oriented surface with nonempty boundary a disjoint union of oriented circles $C_i$, we can define the degree of a map $f: \partial \Sigma \to S^1$ by the sum of the degrees of $f|_{C_i}$. That is, $\text{deg }(f) = \sum_i \text{deg } (f|_{C_i})$. McDuff and Salamon's proof of a lemma (2.71) relies on that if a map $f: \partial \Sigma \to S^1$ extends to a map $\Sigma \to S^1$ then $\deg(f) = 0$.

It's a standard exercise about homotopies that this is true when $\Sigma $ is the disk, in which case extending over the disk is equivalent to being null-homotopic. With a bit of thought, this is also true when $\Sigma$ is a cylinder. However, I'm struggling to see why this is true for a general surface $\Sigma$ with nonempty boundary and can't manage to find a proof of this fact online.

Am I missing something straightforward? And how should one see that this is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick a triangulation of $\Sigma$ and consider $\partial\Sigma$ as a $1$-cycle.  Then $\partial\Sigma$ is a boundary, namely the boundary of the $2$-chain given by adding up all the $2$-simplices of $\Sigma$ with compatible orientations.  It follows that any map $f:\Sigma\to S^1$ maps $\partial\Sigma$ to a chain in $S^1$ that is a boundary.  But this exactly means that $\deg(f)=0$, since the degree is exactly the homology class of $f_*([\partial\Sigma])$ in $H_1(S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

(More generally, without needing triangulations, it follows from the theory of Poincaré duality that if $M$ is a compact oriented $n$-manifold, the connecting homomorphism $H_n(M,\partial M)\to H_{n-1}(\partial M)$ maps the fundamental class of $(M,\partial M)$ to the fundamental class of $\partial M$.  It follows that the fundamental class of $\partial M$ maps to $0$ in $H_{n-1}(M)$, i.e. it is a boundary when considered as a cycle in $M$.)

Comment: I have some questions. 1) How could you get $\deg(f) = 0$? Is it because $f : \Sigma \to \mathbb{S}^1$ restricted on $\partial \Sigma$ is a function mapped to a boudary of $\mathbb{S}^1$(i.e. a point)? I can't see why it is true. 2) How the last paragraph related to the your answer? It seems intuitive but I can't see the direct relation. Could you explain more precisely?

Comment: 1) The point is that the 1-cycle $\partial\Sigma$ in $C_1(\Sigma)$ is a boundary, so $[\partial\Sigma]\in H_1(\Sigma)$ is $0$.  Thus $f_*([\partial\Sigma])=0$ as well.  But $f_*([\partial\Sigma])=\sum_i f_*([C_i])$ is by definition the same as $\deg f$ when you identify $H_1(S^1)$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ in the canonical way.

Comment: 2) The key ingredient in the argument was the fact that $[\partial \Sigma]\in H_1(\Sigma)$ was $0$.  The point of my last paragraph is to explain that this is true more generally for manifolds with boundary and can be proved without a triangulation on $\Sigma$.